# PageSpeed Insights not working on mobile, but works on desktop

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Website is: https://stemhub-f5758.web.app/

Works perfectly fine on desktop, but on mobile I get this error everytime: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Example: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-stemhub-f5758-web-app/t4pseiaxpq?form_factor=mobile

Tried it 5 times now still doesn't work